# Is it possible to convert php file into html by clicking on link or button?

Tags: php, html, indexing

I want to convert index.php file into html file for quick response to client. It interacts with database(mysql) only single time in 24 hours. So when it interacts and updates content i would be able to convert it into an html file by clicking on a link or button. it has also include some other php files like header/footer.php.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is [caching](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHMZ_en-GBGB337GB337&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+caching#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHMZ_en-GBGB337GB337&sa=X&ei=15SETeHNIYiahQemsZWyBA&ved=0CBkQvwUoAQ&q=php+caching&spell=1&fp=fb9f0653ea750a81)

Comment: do you only offer single static pages to your clients?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Yes but it(index.php) has a form actioned as any php file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean 'quick response' in the sense that you want pages to load faster or if you mean you want to send your client a static version of the site.

If you mean you want to load pages quicker, you could **cache** pages. Since you only update content once every 24 hours, you could clear the cache once every 24 hours...

[This blog post](http://www.snipe.net/2009/03/quick-and-dirty-php-caching/) gives one method of caching, and at the end he discusses a number of libraries that exist that you can use instead to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather old but perhaps [this article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/caching-php-performance) can direct you into a solution your looking for.

There must also exist caching engines in php. But php has been a while for me so don't know any.